# Deleted pull request commits in a merged pull request

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-merge

So in GitHub, when I make a pull request, it takes all of the commits in the pull request and puts it in the master branch. After that, it then *adds* another commit that says "Merge pull request *NUMBER_HERE* from *BRANCH*"

However, I've noticed that in most repositories, those commits that were part of the pull request aren't in the history.

For example, if there are three commits in a branch, commit A, commit B, and commit C, and you submit a successful pull request, the history looks like :

```
Merge pull request #1 from some_branch
commit C
commit B
commit A
```

But when I look at other repositories, it just looks like :

```
Merge pull request #1 from some_branch
```

Without the commits in the pull request underneath it. In fact, it usually comprises of just a bunch of merged pull requests over and over again, like this :

```
Merge pull request #3 from some_branch
Merge pull request #2 from some_other_branch
Merge pull rqeuest #1 from yet_again_another_branch
```

Have I been doing it wrong the wrong time? Or is it supposed to be common convention to delete commit C, commit B, and commit A, leaving just the "Merge pull request" commit? I can't seem to find anything about this online.

**EDIT :**

For clarification, this is what I mean :
[image]

There are two merge pull requests right next to each other, and the commit under the 2nd pull request is unrelated to it.

There are no intermediate commits between them, which means that the commits inside the pull request were deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Commits are not necessarily just below the "Merge pull request" commit. On the commits page on github, the commits are sorted by time the commits were authored**.

You will get a clearer picture on the network graph page.

** Unless there's a rebase involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is configurable, you can enable "Allow squash merging" then no matter how many commits that a PR contains, they will be squeezed into 1 single commit.
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/configuring-commit-squashing-for-pull-requests